# How can I retrieve the queue name for a service bus queue from my remote Azure App Configuration using the Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

The function app I'm working on works perfectly when setting my config using a local.settings.json file.  I have set up a new App Configuration in Azure to manage the properties remotely but I have been getting the following error on startup:

```
[2022-04-01T14:34:07.209Z] The 'QueueTrigger' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.QueueTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: '%QueueName%' does not resolve to a value.
```

I'm picking up the correct connection string value without any issues but it appears that the queueName property of the @ServiceBusQueueTrigger is not detecting the queue name variable I have set in the azure config.

```
@FunctionName("QueueTrigger")
public void serviceBusProcess(
        @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(
            name = "message", 
            queueName = "%QueueName%", 
            connection = "QueueConnectionString"
        ) String message, final ExecutionContext context) {

    // process message

}
```

Is there a way to insert this variable without having to hard-code the value?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from a .NET perspective, I haven't found a solution until today than hardcoding the value. I guess it is required by the runtime to bind to the queue to the trigger.

Comment: In .net you can define queue name like this "%QueueNameFromSettins%"

Comment: Good to know - you never stop learning. Thanks :)